# How to make Jenkins job wait for other job to complete?

Tags: jenkins, gerrit-trigger

I have a job "JobA" which creates a gerrit and does CR+2 on it, the CR+2 evet is going to trigger JobB, I want JobA to wait for JobB's completion before exiting, is this possible? if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want with jenkins pipeline plugin. That would be simplified pipeline definition of JobA:

```
node
{
    // create a gerrit
    build job: 'JobB'
    // steps after JobB finishes
}
```